# Wisdom of the Crowd Disagreement Probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, bernoulli-distribution, set-theory

I'm trying to estimate the likelihood that a set of annotators will have at least one dissenter.  For n annotations, we know the probability that they will annotate any given record P(a) and the probability that they'll annotate the record correctly P(true).

As a simple example if we have the following values:

Annotator A
P(a): .35
P(true): .9

Annotator B
P(a): .45
P(true): .95

Annotator C
P(a): .7
P(true): .85

I can simulate this scenario and get roughly 11.67% of the annotations having some disagreement, but I'm stumped on how to generalize the calculation.

Presumably, I need to know the weighted probability of a correctly annotated record along with the average number of annotators per record.

Appreciate the help.